# WrapBootstrap templates license explained

Tags: licensing

I have some hard time understanding this license and what exactly means: [wrap bootstrap license details](http://support.wrapbootstrap.com/knowledge_base/topics/usage-licenses)

Basically my question is: what license I need to purchase for a template if I want to use that template to build a software as a service (SaaS) app? Users can use it for free (limited functionality) or pay a monthly fee (all functionality available). I host the app in the cloud.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: I contacted wrapbootstrap to clearify and the answer is wrong. I am writing a new question with answer provided and details in the relevant Stackexchange community "Startups" 
https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/wrapbootstrap-template-license-explained/12504#12504

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though this is off topic question still i would like to answer it. I regularly buy theme from both wrapbootstrap and themeforest.

I think you need to buy single application license if you buy from wrap bootstrap thats awesome thing about wrapbootstrap while themeforest suck if you charge user you have to pay 50x price of single license and get extended license for single product.

According to wrapbootstrap docs it states about every license.

Use of an item is bound by the license you purchase. A license grants you a non-exclusive and non-transferrable right to use and incorporate the item in your personal or commercial projects.

For more info : http://support.wrapbootstrap.com/knowledge_base/topics/usage-licenses

Comment: I think following terms make it confusing.
"You must not incorporate the item in a work which is created for redistribution or resale by you or your client.
The item may not be redistributed or resold."
So if I am building a web app which is licesne protected(commercial license) then I can not buy single app license(?) since I am redistributing the app by selling it.

Comment: @PratikPatel It depends if you are creating a SaaS product which you will use on single website then single license is fine. If you are creating a product for eg CRM that you will distribute then you should buy commercial license.

Comment: @Abhishek I want to buy a template from wrapbootstrap, and need to use it as my ecommerce site's UI; In that case, should I want to go with Single Application License or Multiple Applications license?  and is there any drawbacks if I purchase as Single License? please suggest.. Thanks!

Comment: @Abhishek any tips for me :)

Comment: @PrashanthSams Please note this isn't a legal advice you should also read wrapbootstrap terms, ecommerce would be single license. So basically anything which you are not redistributing or not using for multiple projects is single license.

Comment: I contacted wrapbootstrap to clearify and the answer is wrong. I am writing a new question with answer provided and details in the relevant Stackexchange community "Startups" 
https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/wrapbootstrap-template-license-explained/12504#12504

Answer (score 5):

There is a fine line when using a SaaS based application.

I am a student of IP law. I deal with these fine prints for the most part of my day. It is better to be safe than sorry as having the wrong license in the end will result in much bigger fines.

If you modified the template and want to resell the end product, then the platform used for it does not matter that much; in this case SaaS is used to sell the users access/time to the product you created, so in essence you are reselling the product.

For this purpose you would need to obtain an extended license.

Comment: Does it mean that all web applications which charges users for access are required to use extended license even if template is not modified and is just a part of large application?

Comment: @PratikPatel That is correct, the extended license will need to be applied. And BTW you do need to modify the template and it has to be just a part of the larger application (this is the requirement for all wrapbootstrap's licenses not just the extended)

Comment: I contacted wrapbootstrap to clearify and the answer is wrong. I am writing a new question with answer provided and details in the relevant Stackexchange community "Startups" 
https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/wrapbootstrap-template-license-explained/12504#12504

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio "Couldn't find startups.stackexchange.com"

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio wrapbootstrap licenses are very vague, they were also sued recently and the was fined $85,000 for image copyright issues. I suggest you do not take these matters likely because if the author does decide to sue you  for not having the correct license wrapbootstrap will not help you.

Comment: @ThomasSzteliga 
startups.exchange has been closed
Their answer was clear. You need the extended license with either Wrap Bootstrap or Envato (around 1200$) to use the template for commercial purposes.
The best choice is using OpenSource libraries to build your app and avoid templates. You should build a customized experience for your user. 
If you are not a company making more then 100k $ per year, don't worry about lawsuit, but I would just use the c003 images/videos and avoid templates.
Once companies reach relavant popularity you will need to have a license for every image